# "error : Root element is missing." cant launch solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, hololens

The visual studio solution file created during build process (SDK: Universal 10, UWP Build Type: D3D) won't load anymore with the following error:

GeneratedProjects\UWP\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.csproj : error : Root element is missing.

Previously its been fine, I've tried reinstalling Visual studios and Unity using the hololens software install site links (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/install_the_tools) but still I keep getting the same error.

Unity Version : 5.5.1f1
Visual Studio : Community 2015
Windows SDK : 10.0.14393.795

Having the same error as this post :

https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/1526/error-root-element-is-missing

tried the posts solution but it didn't work for me.

Any recommendations would be great thanks.